# Filling out the advertising identifiers permissions declaration on Android - react-native/expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-permissions

I am currently working on a react-native application with Expo, and Google keeps reminding me of the following warning every time I upload a build to the stores:

`You need to fill out the advertising identifier declaration to publish an app targeting Android 13 (API 33). We will use this declaration to provide security measures in the Play Console, taking into account changes to the advertising identifier in Android 13. Apps targeting Android 13 or higher and using an advertising identifier must include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission in the manifest file.`

I have already added the following line to the **AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="*xxxxx*" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

And also in the **App.json**, just in case:

```
"android": {
"permissions": [
"com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID",
],
```

However, the warning still appears when I publish a version of my app on the Google Play Console. Is this normal, or is there a specific procedure that needs to be followed?

Thank you